# Grammatical structure: Too kind a girl

Tags: grammar, adjectives, articles, big-mess-construction

Is this structure correct?

Too + adjective + article + noun

**For example:** She's too kind a girl to refuse making tea.

Is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Basically, the preposition "of" has been elided, so it's basically a prepositional phrase, with "a" standing in for "of a".  Not exactly formal speech, but common.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this structure is commonly found in English, but the article can only be the indefinite article.

> ([ref.](http://masteringarticles.com/the-indefinite-and-definite-article-with-adjectives/)) The indefinite article may also appear between an adjective and a noun when using the word too.

Here are, for instance, the most common nouns found when the adjective is "hard".

[image]

Here are those for "difficult".

[image]

It always means "sb/sth is **a** < noun > so < adj. > that it is not possible that < what follows > should not be true".

Comment: Needs sources and links to make it an acceptable answer.

Answer (score -2):

In "She's too kind a girl to refuse making tea", the "too kind a" is basically "too kind **of** a", with the preposition "of" elided.  This is not strictly "proper" grammar, but is very common, and would only generate objections from very strict grammarians.

As such, what you have is a prepositional phrase, consisting of "[of] a girl".

As close as I can parse it:

> She [subject] is [verb] too kind [object] of a girl [prepositional
>   phrase modifying "too kind"] to refuse making tea [prepositional
>   phrase also modifying "too kind"]

Comment: "Very strict grammarians" are more likely to criticize *too kind of a*. The original construction is *too kind a [noun]*; adding *of* is a less broadly distributed and apparently more recent alternative construction. Relevant NYT article: https://www.nytimes.com/1997/02/09/magazine/of-of-a.html where William Safire in 1997 wrote that "of a" "took hold about 20 years ago, only in America and almost exclusively in spoken English"